# Why does Visual studio 2010 hang when entering debug?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When running my code in debug, and a breakpoint hits, the first keyboard click will stuck the whole VS.

I tried to create a new solution on my computer to eliminate the idea of netweork problems and the problem did not occure.

I also tried to unload all 65 projects in the solution and the problem did not occure.

So, Do you know why and how can i solve this hang?

Thanks in advance,
Oz Radiano.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try to find the problem with the logging of VS2010:
http://saraford.net/2005/10/20/use-devenv-log-to-troubleshoot-vs-issues/